# shorter, cleaner, and faster implementation of volatility of time series in python

Tags: python, inline, list-comprehension

I have been working with python for some time, but I still need to get to its full potential.

I know I could solve the problem with some for loops, etc, but that's too boring and I want to learn something new :)

I am trying to compute the volatility (v = std of returns, returns = today's value - yesterday's value) of a dictionary of time series called: time_series.
Every element ts in time_series is composed of a tuple (date, value)
As outcome, I would like to have a vector of volatilities.

What I am currently doing: I am ordering the time series by key (I have to), and then, for every time series, if it contains more than 1 value, I compute the returns and their standard deviation, otherwise I return 0.

I am currently working under the assumption that the time series are already ordered according to the date.

This is what I got so far:

```
time_series = {'A': [(20130101, 1.0), (20130102, 1.1), (20130103, 1.3)], 'B': [(20130101, 1.0), (20130102, 1.1), (20130103, 1.4)]}
sorted_keys = sorted(time_series.keys())
v = [ scipy.std( [ time_series[ts_id][i+1][1] - time_series[ts_id][i][1] for i in range(len(time_series[ts_id])-1) ] ) if len(time_series[ts_id]) > 1 else 0 for ts_id in sorted_keys ]
print v
[0.049999999999999933, 0.099999999999999867]
```

I know it is an ugly 1 line statment and that's why I'm now here :)..
Is there a way to make this either shorter or cleaner or better performing while keeping the comprehension?

I am curious about all 3 outcomes.

I did not manage to sort the time series itself (for now). Is there a way to do it, while keeping everything as compact as possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Throughout this post you've assumed that short ⇒ clean, even though it most definitely does not. // Also, a runnable sample would make it so much easier to help.

Comment: hi, I did not mean that actually, I'll rewrite the paragraph then.
I am curious about all of the 3 possible outcomes

Comment: Well, you can shorten the code to `[scipy.std([t1[1]-t0[1] for t1, t0 in zip(ts[1:], ts)] or [0]) for id, ts in sorted(time_series.items(), key=itemgetter(0))]` but I couldn't see any obvious improvements that don't distil to "use a better data type" and "loops are not evil".

Answer (score 0):

I think this is fine but maybe you want something like this?

```
v = time_series.values()
for value in v:
    print value
    returns = []
    returns.append(value[i+1] - value[i])
```

then apply sci.std to returns..